# C# encoding text RLE method

Tags: c#, arrays, counter

I'm trying to pack a given byte array by 'removing' repeated bytes, something like this:

1. Entrance 255 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 200 15 10
2. Output  1x255 2x1 5x4 1x200 1x15 1x10 => 255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10

If one byte is repeated more than 3 times I replace it with the counter.

I began with making a temporary byte list with no repeated values and list with numbers of appearances. I've got a problem with the counter though:

```
public static void compressBlock(List<byte> buffer)
    {
        byte marker = buffer.Last();

        int counter = 1;


        byte[] buffer_ar = new byte[buffer.Count];
        buffer_ar = buffer.ToArray();

        List<byte> temp = new List<byte>();
        List<int> tmp = new List<int>();


       int indeks = 0;
            while (true)
            {


                if (buffer_ar[indeks] == buffer_ar[indeks + 1])
                {
                    counter++;

                    if (buffer_ar[indeks] != buffer_ar[indeks + 1])
                    {
                        temp.Add(buffer_ar[indeks]);
                        tmp.Add(counter);
                        //counter = 1;
                    }


                }

                else
                {
                    //counter = 1;
                    temp.Add(buffer_ar[indeks]);
                    tmp.Add(counter);

                }

                indeks++;
                //counter = 1;

                if (buffer_ar.Length -1 <= indeks) { break; }

            }
```

As the output I have:

byte list: 255 1 4 200 15 10

int list: 1 2 6 6 6 6

I know I have to reset the counter at some point, but when I do that as the output of the int list I have: 1 1 1 1 1 1.

Could someone point me in the right direction to do that?

Comment: Side note: so *different* inputs ` 255 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 200 15 10` and `255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10` should produce the *same output*  `255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10`?

Comment: 255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10 <-- it's an output not the input.

Comment: suppose, that `255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10` *is* the input, what is the output then?

Comment: on my byte[] temp it would be: 255 1 5 4 200 15 10, on final compressed block it would be 255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10 because there is no point adding the counter because it wouldn't reduce the number of bytes

Comment: and, please, see: *different* inputs i.e. `255 1 1 4 4 4 4 4 200 15 10` and `255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10` will produce the *same output* `255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10`, so how can you *decode* it back? Should `5 4` be decoded "as is" `5 4` or be expanded into `4 4 4 4 4`?

Comment: i want to append two list: one with the values and one with the counter, the counter points the number of repetition of the value. To recognize the counter I'll add unique marker. I didn't mention the marker in my question, because I try to deal with the counter right now. That compression method it's called unique value method (it's similiar to RLE method, but rle doesn't have the marker and operates on characters or bits so it's easy to recognize the counter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some issues with you implementation:

1. Decode is impossible since *different inputs* like `1 1 1 1` and `4 1` produce the *same output*: `4 1`
2. What if the same items appears more than *255* (`255 == Byte.MaxValue`) times?
3. Better use general `IEnumerable<Byte>` then `concrete List<Byte>`
4. You don't need any *buffer*, just *count* the last item occurrence.

   ```
   public static IEnumerable<Byte> RleEncode(IEnumerable<Byte> source)
   {
       if (null == source)
           throw new ArgumentNullException("source");

       const int threshold = 3;

       Byte current = 0;
       int count = 0;

       foreach (var item in source) 
           if ((count == 0) || (current == item)) 
           {
               current = item; 
               count += 1;
           }
           else 
           { 
               if (count <= threshold)
                   for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                       yield return current;
               else 
               {
                   for (int i = 0; i < count / Byte.MaxValue; ++i) 
                   {
                       yield return Byte.MaxValue;
                       yield return current;
                   }

                   if (count % Byte.MaxValue != 0) 
                   {
                       yield return (Byte) (count % Byte.MaxValue);
                       yield return current;
                   }
              }

              current = item;
              count = 1;
          }

          // Tail
          if (count <= threshold)
              for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
                  yield return current;
          else 
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < count / Byte.MaxValue; ++i) 
              {
                  yield return Byte.MaxValue;
                  yield return current;
              }

              if (count % Byte.MaxValue != 0) 
              {
                  yield return (Byte) (count % Byte.MaxValue);
                  yield return current;
              }
          }
      }
   ```

Test

```
  List<Byte> source = new List<Byte> {
    255, 1, 1, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 200, 15, 10
  };

  // 255 1 1 5 4 200 15 10 
  String test = String.Join(" ", RleEncode(source));
```

Comment: I've just explained the issue with decoding in the comment  above. But you're right about 'if the same items appears more than 255 times' - I didn't think of that.

Comment: Anyway your answer helped me a lot. Thank you!

Comment: Well, you have to modify it (add the *marker* at least); I've proposed more than `255` items problem solution: imagine that input text is `1..1 (300) times`; how would you encode it? `300` *can't* be encoded as single `byte`; I've output it like that: `255 1 45 1`, however there're other solutions. You're welcome, you've asked a good question, a bit underdesigned, IMHO,

Comment: Just abort and write a new repeat after the byte is full? It's not hard...

Answer (score 0):

You will never get here

```
if (buffer_ar[indeks] != buffer_ar[indeks + 1])
```

because it is placed inside the inverted if

```
if (buffer_ar[indeks] == buffer_ar[indeks + 1])
```

So you would never add the counter to your array